# trigger update copy information

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that does the following:
copy one column of info `jobnumber` from one table (`jobs`) to another (materials) on an existing record to `attachedjobnumber`.

I haven't found the correct syntax to say this. when I insert a new job - nothing gets update and no new row is inserted,,, but there are no error messages in the logs.

I also need to set the bool (`hasjobnumber`) equal to true - when I test that trigger - it works fine.

which makes me think that setting the value of `material.attachedjobnumber = jobs.jobnumber` is the problem, my guess is that `jobs.jobnumber` isn't in reference when updating table material...

if that's true - what's the proper syntax for this?

I've tested separate triggers, and so far this trigger works fine.

```
UPDATE material 
SET isjobyet = "HAS"  
WHERE barcode1 IN (
SELECT primaryRFID
FROM jobs
WHERE jobs.primaryRFID = material.barcode1
)
```

since this code does work - I make the assumption that the non-static `JobNumber` value is the source of the problem. since "**HAS**" is correctly updated.

```sql
UPDATE material 
SET material.AttachedJobNumber = jobs.JobNumber  
WHERE barcode1 IN (
SELECT primaryRFID
FROM jobs
WHERE jobs.primaryRFID = material.barcode1
)
```

from this - I expect that after each inserts on the table jobs:

> `jobs.JobNumber` be assigned to the `material.AttachedJobName`

this updates only the material row where the `material.barcode1 =jobs.primaryrfid`.

but no new row is inserted at all.

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform UPDATE,
Actually you can use the same script using SELECT [skip the UPDATE SYNTAX]
That way you can monitor your script without committing anything yet.

And also I dont recommend using this inside the subquery

```
WHERE jobs.primaryRFID = material.barcode1
```

This condition connecting  a table works on IN-SELECT subquery.

If you are performing subqueries inside the [WHERE] clause, try to treat it as different buffer, dont connect them first.